# Is there a name for the effect that appears from the eyes when someone in anime/manga fights?

Tags: tropes

The following image shows an effect that appears from the eyes when someone fights.

[image]

Is there a name for it?

Answer (score 1):

The closest we can come to a name for this type of trope is [Magical Eye Streamers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicalEyeStreamers).

Answer (score -2):

the animation style is called sakuga where the features are distorted to be made to look superhuman.

Comment: Sakuga refers to a sequence of animation and is not bound by a particular style. Such trope may be considered sakuga, but not all sakuga can be referred to by this trope.